# Composer setup - "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows, xampp, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer, but it showing an error message. I'm using Windows 8.1, and download composer Windows Installer from https://getcomposer.org/download/.

> The command interpreter did not run correctly:
>   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

The cmd file is existing on C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe. And it run normally

Comment: What command do you run to generate that error message?

Comment: This error message shows from Composer-Setup on Windows Installer. It's the screenshot http://i68.tinypic.com/315y83t.jpg

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't even know there _was_ a graphical installer for Composer on Windows. All I see is instructions to run some PHP commands…

Answer (score 0):

1- Open cmd.exe ( administrator mode ).

2- Write this command `sfc /scannow` (My be take long time for scanning).

2- Re-install composer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to Antivirus, Disabled the Antivirus temporarily and try installing again. Thanks